# How sizeThat's fits calculate the size ? ios

Tags: ios, uitextview, ios9, sizetofit

I need to calculate the height of a textView.

I am using tow different ways:

1.

```
 CGSize new_size= [self sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)];
        CGFloat newHeight = new_size.height;
        CGRect new_frame = self.frame;
        new_frame.size.height = newHeight;
        [self setFrame:new_frame];
```

2.

```
 CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width,MAXFLOAT);
    NSStringDrawingContext *context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    [paragraphStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: self.font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle };

    CGRect frame = [self.text boundingRectWithSize:size
                                           options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin)
                                        attributes:attributes
                                           context:context];

    CGFloat newHeight = frame.size.height;
    CGRect new_frame = self.frame;
    new_frame.size.height = newHeight;
    [self setFrame:new_frame];
```

some times they return the same height, and some times the second approach return height < from the first approach.

but all the time the first approach return the correct height !

what's the problem with the second approach ?

**EDIT:**
i've note : that when the `height < 59`, both function return the same thing, and when `height >59` the first approach return the correct height. and the second one return 59.

**EDIT:**
it appears that when i use the system font:

```
[self setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]]
```

both approaches above work correctly.

but when i use another font:

```
[self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:15]]
```

then the second approach doesn't work correctly.

why this happened ?

Comment: Are you sure you're using NSLineBreakByCharWrapping? Not NSLineBreakByWordWrapping? Maybe that, or something among the other options, is different than properties on your textView?

Comment: @johnyu thank you for your reply, also if i set NSLineBreakByWordWrapping , the second approach return different length.

Comment: @johnyu i've edit the question